# Best way to design an API with flask-restful where one resource which has relationship with two parent resources

Tags: rest, api, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful

let's say I have three resources User, Store and Item. User will be parent resource of Store and Store will be another parent resource of the Item resource. Now if a User do a GET request to view the items for a particular store 
i.e. `https://example.com/user/<user_id>/store/<store_id>/items/`

I want make 3 default store available for all the users after registration. The Users will only be able to modify Items.

Or, Should I make it like User will have child of Item resource and Store will have child of Item resource. So store_id will join the Store resource with Item.

What will be the best approach for this kind of REST API

Answer (score 0):

Just you define API Class, like below

```
class UserStoreItemManage(Resource):
    def get(self, user_id, store_id):
        (...)
```

and just add resource like this.

```
api.add_resource(UserStoreItemManage, "/user/<user_id>/store/<store_id>/items/")
```

It works.

If you using flask_restful, you don't always have to crate classes belong models(tables).

Just specify the module name like `UserStoreItemManage`.
It will be fine.

Comment: I want make 3 default store available for all the users after registration. The Users will only be able to modify Items. This is the answer I was looking for. I know how to do it in that way using the flask-restful